# How to force a .net WCF client to use NTLM in an basicHttpBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client, ntlm

right now I have the security node defined like this:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Im getting the following error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your [clientCredentialType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731334.aspx) to "**Ntlm**".

Comment: ***transport clientCredentialType="Windows"***