# Error connecting to WCF service from its hosting server

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, ntlm

This may be stupid/not possible. However, what I am trying to achieve is as follows:

- I have a VM hosting WCF web services in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008
- I am using the basichttp binding
- The client code runs perfectly on other machines
- This server VM also needs to perform batch processing so I need to use the client access to these WCF services on it
- When run on the actual box hosting the WCF services I get...

  System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  Server stack trace: 
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

  Exception rethrown at [0]: 
     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

What I am wondering is whether what I am attempting is actually possible - I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to connect to a service from the hosting machine but the specifics may prevent me - and if it is, what changes do I need to make to my settings to achieve it?

The dll concerned sets up the binding as follows...

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
    binding.OpenTimeout = openTimeout;
    binding.SendTimeout = sendTimeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = receiveTimeout;
    binding.CloseTimeout = closeTimeout;

    return binding;
```

Output of cscript authentication is...

```
NTAuthenticationProviders       : (STRING) "Negotiate,NTLM"
```

The service is set to demand membership of a network group for which the user connecting is a member (PrincipalPermission).

As indicated in the comments below, I have viewed the security event log and found that when the user (network account) connects as a client to the WCF service on the host machine there is an entry complaining that the account failed to logon - a Null SID is passed.

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       *<network account>*
    Account Domain:     *<account domain>*

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0x0
```

The question is, why is this happening?

Comment: Check the client configuration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134119/how-to-force-a-net-wcf-client-to-use-ntlm-in-an-basichttpbinding

Comment: The client has no configuration - it's a DLL - so the setup is performed programmatically. The line binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType performs the setting to NTLM. I believe the issue is due to me running the client code on the server that's hosting the service as this works elsewhere. I just don't know what to change.

Comment: I've also tried changing the client to using Windows rather than NTLM. Get similar knock-back but with Ntlm swapped with Negotiate in the error message. I'm certain this is an "only on the server" issue, maybe WCF, maybe IIS config etc.

Comment: I have now looked at the Security event log for this on the server concerned and it seems that the WCF service is receiving a Null SID for the account when it connects as a client on the service host. Question is, why is the SID null?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 on this [post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) does the trick...

DisableStrictNameChecking = 1
BackConnectionHostNames = in my case, the full domain name qualified alias for the server